# Pyinstaller missing dlls, exe not working

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller to make an exe for window 10 right now.

My Biggest question is how comes that I am able to run and work perfectly by running the program from my IDE. But when i use pyinstaller it is missing many dlls and doesnt work?

I am using the code

```
"Pyinstaller.py Main.py"
```

Tried also `--onefile, --windowed options..`

What is the correct way to import all my 3rd party modules to the pyinstaller?

I am working on windows 10 64bit with python 2.7.

Those are the libs missing durng pyinstaller making the exe:
9661 WARNING: lib not found: LIBEAY32.dll
10082 WARNING: lib not found: SSLEAY32.dll
11941 WARNING: lib not found: libmysql.dll

Also those are the missing dll from warnMain.txt created in build folder.
There are too many of them to show here.

I read before about hooks that maybe I should create for the program to see the dlls or point it to path where all the dlls located.

Never made it to work, maybe done something wrong.

Please i really need your help guys!

Comment: You should add all the missing modules by using the [`--hidden-import` option](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) at the command line or the `.spec` file.

Answer (score -1):

remove the --windowed option from Pyinstaller command.

Then, when you run the exe file, you will see much more accurate error.

post a print after running exe...

Comment: This should really be a comment and not an anwer.